# Displaying activity with blur effect in Android Tabs

Tags: android

I have a tab bar in my application, with third tab named About. When user clicks on this About tab, I want activity to be displayed with blur effect. More specifically, About activity should be on front, while previous tab should be displayed behind with blur effect. I did the following code in the about.java onCreate Method, but it opens new window and the previous windows are not being displayed.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //This is the code used to add blur effect
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);
}
```

If I do it without tab bar it works. Any suggestions on what might be going wrong or how to do it in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. I added few of the Styles in res/value/styles.xml file and added the theme in AndroidMenifest.xml file.

Comment: Can you please share those styles you used?

Comment: @MuhammadZahabAhmedKhan, Apologies I do not have that project now. Let me know what is your problem and I can try to fix that for you

Comment: I want a blurry screen effect like fog. And when some one draw with finger on it. It behaves like mirror of car having fog on it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643675/create-a-foggy-effect-on-screen?lq=1 
here is the image what i want.