# Create a foggy effect on screen

Tags: android

Is it possible to create a fog effect on the screen of an android phone. iFoggy was able to get this effect (see picture) for an iPhone.

[image]

Is it possible to achieve the same for an android app. I just want the foggy effect and don't want anything to happen when the user touches the screen.

I'm guessing this might be achieved using Bitmap but I've never used that before so any tips would be helpful.

Comment: Would you need to be able to interact with whatever is under the fog?

Comment: There would be a button behind the fog which the user can press to clear the screen

Comment: Would you be seeing the users home screen under the fog?

Comment: It would display the current app's activity under the fog

Comment: It is likely doable, I am not sure about the button the fog... You could set the source of an imageview to your foggy image and make the activity transparent.

Comment: I thought about that but using a blurred image of the background won't be easy as the background changes depending on what the user did with it before the fog effect was called

Comment: Use a transparent png and place it on top of the content, quite easy. Heart cut-out is transparent.

Comment: @Erwinus is right and check this out regarding the background of the activity. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989140/displaying-activity-with-blur-effect-in-android-tabs) to have `Blur Effect` for your screen

Comment: I had a look. The answer wasn't really of much help as the person figured it out himself and didn't really explain how

Answer (score -1):

Make a transparent activity. Refer this answer. [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)
And set the background for the layout of this activity, a transparent PNG file. Here is the PNG file.
[click](http://www.4shared.com/photo/m2MUv2AV/SmOke.html)

Comment: NO PNG file available in link you have provided at least attach in SO instead of providing link

Comment: @Pratik I didn't had permission to attach image in SO when I answered this question. Thats why I provided the link.